# URL initializer gives incorrect URL of web link in Swift 4

Tags: string, url, swift4, urlencode

I am trying to use some web link for downloading images.

My URL sample is like:

```
let link = "www.XYZ.com/2018/02/01/thumbnails/Source-01-February-2018-20:00.jpg"
```

I am encoding this as below:

```
if let urlString = URL(string: link.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed))
```

but it gives me an output URL like:

```
Optional<URL>
  ▿ some : www.XYZ.com/2018/02/01/thumbnails/Source-01-February-2018- ... 1:00.jpg
```

I don't know why it replaces file name **Source-01-February-2018-20:00.jpg** to **Source-01-February-2018- ... 1:00.jpg** with triple dots (...) in the encoded URL.

Please help, how can I get the same correct URL?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behavior.

When you print the variable's value out, it gets **shortened** in the console, but that does not affect the value of the URL.

To prove this, print out `link.absoluteString`:

```swift
print(link?.absoluteString ?? "") /*www.XYZ.com/2018/02/01/thumbnails/Source-01-February-2018-20:00.jpg*/
```

Comment: Still init returns ...  in url like www.XYZ.com/2018/02/01/thumbnails/Source-01-February-2018- ... 1:00.jpg, file name replaced Source-01-February-2018-20:00.jpg to Source-01-February-2018- ... 1:00.jpg